# How to display data from two tables into one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, show

I use Ruby v 3. I want to display data from 2 tables into one form.
My models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :number, :street

  validates :city, :presence => true
  validates :number, :presence => true
  validates :street, :presence => true

  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  attr_accessible :name, :phone, :surname, :address_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

My form looks alike:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :address_attributes do |p| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.label :city %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.label :street %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :street %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= p.label :number %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :number %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I use fields_for method. And my controller is here:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.address_attributes = @user.address
end
```

It does not working and I totally don't know why. When I click edit on address list i've got an error:

```
 undefined method `with_indifferent_access'
```

Anyone can help me figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Episodes 196 and 197 on RailsCasts:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

There is a revised episode for 196, for which you will need to subscribe to RailsCasts.

I would highly recommend subscribing to learning sites like RailsCasts and CodeSchool, to lear RoR faster **and** in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(parmas[:id])
end
```

and on your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :address do |p| %>
```

and see if it works, you don't have to add the attributes